# Error while doing XStream.fromXML - Serialization

Tags: java, serialization, xstream

I have problem with deserialization XML file with XStream.
Problem is with class JLanguageTab. I know this because when I change it to other class which is suitable with XML everything is OK.

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot deserialize object with new readObject()/writeObject() methods
---- Debugging information ----
class               : xxx.XMLStaticMessages
required-type       : xxx.JLanguageTab
path                : /staticMessages/staticMessage/languageVersion
line number         : 1
-------------------------------
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializableConverter.doUnmarshal(SerializableConverter.java:253)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:125)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:56)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:45)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:46)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:195)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:125)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:56)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:45)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:46)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:195)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:125)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:56)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:45)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:46)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:117)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.ReferenceByXPathMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(ReferenceByXPathMarshallingStrategy.java:29)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:846)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:833)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:781)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:773)
at com.procom.staticmessages.XMLStaticMessagesFactory.getStaticMessages(XMLStaticMessagesFactory.java:49)
at xxx.XMLStaticMessagesFactory.getStaticMessages(XMLStaticMessagesFactory.java:18)
at cxxx.StaticMessagesForm.jMenuItemOpenActionPerformed(StaticMessagesForm.java:341)
at xxx.StaticMessagesForm.access$900(StaticMessagesForm.java:21)
at xxx.StaticMessagesForm$9.actionPerformed(StaticMessagesForm.java:241)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:356)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Actions.actionPerformed(BasicMenuItemUI.java:802)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1661)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2879)
at javax.swing.JMenuBar.processBindingForKeyStrokeRecursive(JMenuBar.java:689)
at javax.swing.JMenuBar.processBindingForKeyStrokeRecursive(JMenuBar.java:697)
at javax.swing.JMenuBar.processBindingForKeyStrokeRecursive(JMenuBar.java:697)
at javax.swing.JMenuBar.processKeyBinding(JMenuBar.java:668)
at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireBinding(KeyboardManager.java:306)
at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireKeyboardAction(KeyboardManager.java:292)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindingsForAllComponents(JComponent.java:2971)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2963)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2842)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1890)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:752)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1017)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:889)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:717)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Class code: http://pastebin.com/RijdmTe0

Comment: It's not a good idea to serialize the class `JLanguageTab`, because it inherits from `javax.swing.JPanel` and contains a lot of boilerplate code. What is your reason to serialize this class?

Comment: XStream need to (De)Serialize it while loading / saving xml.

Comment: I don't know what your use-case is, but maybe it would be better to store only the real business data in xml. Then you can load the xml file on startup, create a new `JLanguageTab` instance and initialize the new instance with the loaded data from xml file.